# Quando non si deve mettere l'accento sul pronome "sé"?

Tags: grammar, orthography

Ho letto che "sé" è la forma forte del pronome riflessivo in espressioni come, per esempio, "far da sé", "essere fuori di sé", "parlare di sé"... Comunque, mi hanno detto che a volte non si deve mettere l'accento su questo pronome come, ad esempio, nella espressione "se stesso". Non riesco a capire quando non debba scrivere l'accento nel suddetto pronome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Secondo il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/se/) l'accento dovrebbe essere messo *sempre*. Cito:

> Assai spesso, come compl. oggetto ma anche con i complementi già
>   veduti, è rafforzato da *stesso* o da *medesimo*:
>
> > credendo d’ingannare gli altri inganna sé stesso
> >     non se la deve prendere con me ma con sé stessa
> >     E ’l fiorentino spirito bizzarro In sé medesmo si volvea co’ denti (Dante)
>
> in questi casi il pron. è scritto spesso, **ma senza
>   valide ragioni che lo giustifichino**, senza accento: *se stesso, se
>   medesimo* (**in ogni altro caso la grafia senz’accento è antiquata**).

In altre parole *sé stesso* e *sé medesimo* possono essere scritti senza accento, ma *sarebbe più corretto scriverli **con** l'accento*. In ogni altro caso l'accento *deve* essere presente.

---

L'Accademia della Crusca ha un articolo al riguardo, dove affermano la stessa cosa:
[Accentazione del pronome se stesso](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/accentazione-pronome-stesso)

Cito la conclusione:

> In conclusione, sebbene negli attuali testi di grammatica per le voci
>   rafforzate *se stesso*, *se stessa* e *se stessi* non sia previsto l'uso
>   dell'accento, è preferibile considerare non censurabili entrambe le
>   scelte, mancando in realtà una regola specifica che ne possa stabilire
>   il maggiore o minore grado di correttezza. Si raccomanda di tener
>   conto di questa "irrilevanza" specialmente in sede di valutazione di
>   elaborati scolastici e affini.

Anche qui la conclusione è: *l'accento può essere usato **sempre***, ma le forme *se stesso*/*se medesimo* si possono anche scrivere senza.

Inoltre nel [Vademecum sull'accento: quando indicarlo e dove pronunciarlo](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/vademecum-sullaccento-indicarlo-pronunciarlo) afferma:

> Alcuni, quando il pronome *sé* è seguito da *stesso* e *medesimo*,
>   tralasciano di indicare l'accento, perché in questo caso il se pronome
>   non può confondersi con *se* congiunzione: *se stesso*, *se medesimo*. **Noi,
>   però, consigliamo di indicare l'accento anche in questo caso, e quindi
>   di scrivere *sé stesso*, *sé medesimo*.**

Comment: Comunque a me hanno detto molte volte che "se stesso" va scritto senza l'accento.

Comment: @Charo Confermo che anche a me a scuola (italiana) insegnarono che se stesso non vuole l'accento.

Comment: Allora dovremmo sentire altri pareri come risposta.

Comment: @Charo Ho aggiunto un riferimento all'Accademia della Crusca.

Comment: Curiosamente, ho trovato [questo intervento](http://forum.accademiadellacrusca.it/forum_5/interventi/897.shtml.htlm) sul sito della Crusca, ma penso non sia una risposta ufficiale della Crusca, è soltanto un forum che aveva la Crusca anni fa.

Comment: Non capisco perché non funziona il link: http://forum.accademiadellacrusca.it/forum_5/interventi/897.shtml.html

Comment: @Charo Comunque, sì, quella mi sembra solo una discussione su un forum e l'opinione dell'utente *avemundi* (*a.mondello@...*) non mi pare si possa ritenere molto autorevole. In particolare non ho mai sentito di una regola grammaticale chiamata "principio del massimo risparmio", e anche se esistesse tale principio non potrebbe comunque rendere *errata* la grafia "estesa" con l'accento, ma, al massimo, renderebbe preferibile quella senza.

Comment: Sì, sono d'accordo.

Comment: @Charo: Il fatto di omettere l'accento da “sé stesso” è una di quelle pseudoregolette che vengono ripetute a orecchio, anche nelle scuole, ma che non hanno nessuna ragion d'essere, né nella grammatica né nella pratica, inclusi i testi dei buoni scrittori.

Answer (score 4):

Una ragione che *potrebbe* giustificare l'omissione dell'accento in locuzioni come *sé stesso* e (l'antiquato) *sé medesimo* è che in questi casi il pronome *sé* è clitico.

La regola sui monosillabi accentati che nessuno insegna è molto facile: non vogliono l'accento quelli che sono clitici (proclitici o enclitici), lo vogliono quelli che non lo sono. Naturalmente, condizione essenziale per l'accento è che il monosillabo abbia significati diversi, quindi *sto* non vuole accento anche se non è clitico. Le note musicali non contano in questo ambito, quindi nemmeno *do* vuole accento.

Perciò l'avverbio *lì* vuole l'accento, ma la particella pronominale *li* non lo vuole; l'articolo *la* non vuole l'accento, l'avverbio *là* lo vuole. Analogamente il pronome *si* va senza e l'affermazione *sì* va con l'accento.

La congiunzione *se* è clitica, mentre il pronome *sé* non lo è, tranne quando rafforzato da *stesso* o *medesimo*. È una buona ragione per omettere l'accento in questi casi? Secondo me no: se ci pensiamo, sarebbe ***l'unica*** parola italiana che cambia ortografia a seconda del contesto.

Non vale a questo proposito l'obiezione di *viceré* o *ventitré*, perché qui la parola non è *re* o *tre*, ma una parola composta con l'accento tonico sull'ultima sillaba, quindi l'accento grafico è obbligatorio per regola generale.

Giustificare *se stesso* con il fatto che *non si può fare confusione* è puerile: chi solleva il problema della possibile confusione, come se la cava con *sé stessi*/*se stessi*? Scrive l'accento perché *se stessi* potrebbe essere congiunzione più verbo? Con la *possibile confusione* come criterio si arriva al ridicolo di

> se stesso, se stessa, sé stessi, sé stesse

che non vale la pena discutere oltre.

Comment: Tecnicamente, anche espressioni come "un amante / un'amante" cambiano grafia a seconda del contesto.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Le due parole “un” sono diverse. C'è, viceversa, solo una forma di “sé”.

Answer (score 1):

> Non riesco a capire quando non debba scrivere l'accento nel suddetto pronome.

Quando viene prima del verbo. Es.: "Se ne va" e "se lo vede".

Si veda [qui](http://www.locuta.com/comb.htm) ai punti 8 e 10.

Comment: Si tratta di un pronome diverso.

Comment: Eh... penso che qui esca la mia natura di insegnante. Per lo studente non importa se sul dizionario è un lemma diverso. "se" è comunque "se". Può distinguerlo dal se ipotetico, ma distinguere questo, che è comunque un pronome riflessivo? -.-''